# Deploy Triggers to Prod Without Sufficient Test Coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, deployment, code-coverage

In our case, writing tests for every trigger would be useless and would require a lot of work. That is because all the trigger does is to fire a callout (webhook) - no business logic whatsoever to test.

Further, all triggers call the exact same URL, so writing a test for every action (e.g. create/update/delete) for every trigger would be plain tedious copy/past work.

To make things more complicated, a lot of the entities have mandatory fields, some of which are lookups, which means that to populate them we would have to create entities as a part of the test.

So long story short, is there any way to hack this "cannot deploy without tests" limitation?

Comment: I'm happy to discuss further, but comments are not for extended discussion. I have [moved this conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62468/discussion-on-question-by-orcaman-deploy-triggers-to-prod-without-sufficient-tes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. You must have 1% coverage on triggers (at least 1 line) in order to deploy to production. It doesn't matter the reason, this limitation is baked into the platform.

Typically, once you start getting to the point where you're "copy-pasting" a lot of code, it's time to start building a proper unit test framework. Almost all organizations have a class that fulfills this purpose. For example:

```
@isTest public class TestUtils {
  public static Account createAccount() {
    return new Account(Name='Test', Required_Field__c='ABC');
  }
  public static Contact createContact(Id accountId) {
    return new Contact(AccountId=AccountId, LastName='Test');
  }
}
```

All of your unit tests then use these methods to initialize:

```
Account testAccount = TestUtils.createAccount();
insert testAccount;
Contact testContact = TestUtils.createContact(testAccount.Id);
insert testContact;
// etc...
```

Once you have these methods written and used in all of your unit tests, when an administrator adds a required field, validation rule, etc, you only need to go to one place (TestUtils) to update all of your unit tests at once.

Yes, this is rather annoying to set up. However, it's a required exercise, and it will benefit you in the long run. On a number of occasions, we've avoided potentially production-breaking bugs simply by having proper unit tests.

Comment: testing is awesome, the code that actually does something is fully covered (that's the web service being called from SF). I honestly can't see any logic in writing apex code to test vanilla SF (I don't have any code related to account - why the heck do I need to start testing account create/update/delete just because I fire a request to some url)? Anyways, I'm looking for a hack to overcome this (I don't mind creating the webhooks in production if needed but it looks like this option is blocked as well)

Comment: @orcaman There are non-code solutions you could use to avoid triggers, actually, such as Process Builder to call your class. If you insist on using triggers, you have to have code coverage. As long as your webhook code is covered, you might look into Process Builder/InvocableMethod instead.

Comment: Hey there, thanks. So it looks like there was no way out, I had to write the tests. They were actually much simpler than I though (because, well, as I said, I don't really need to test anything, all the business logic is done in the webservice the trigger calls out to). BTW - I am still not able to deploy. Some other weird salesforce issue - during the validation of the tests in prod, it's now complaining about an invalid value - but the field doesn't exist. :-/ 
Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Apex development?

In general testing any Apex code does require making mock data including related objects. If your data model is particularly intricate you may want to consider loading test data from a Static Resource:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm
If you put all the unit tests in one class you can have a single `TestSetup` method that fills up the DB appropriately for each test.

Testing callouts requires creating mock callouts. Those mocks will have to be at least a little bit contextual (e.g. if the response to a create/update/delete is different, your mock should respond accordingly so your code parses the response without bombing). You obviously can't test if the callout worked right, but you can test that your code correctly handles an expected response.

Comment: testing is awesome, the code that actually does something is fully covered (that's the web service being called from SF). I honestly can't see any logic in writing apex code to test vanilla SF (I don't have any code related to account - why the heck do I need to start testing account create/update/delete just because I fire a request to some url)? Anyways, I'm looking for a hack to overcome this (I don't mind creating the webhooks in production if needed but it looks like this option is blocked as well)

Answer (score 1):

you should have test classes for all the code you are writing in your Org. Writing test classes helps you catch defects when you write different scenarios and assert them to ensure the class is covering the functionality that its supposed to do. By asking for a bypass you may put your project at risk, which i am not sure is the way to go about this.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the test classes test absolutely nothing. All the code does is call a URL. Why on earth would I need to instantiate a crazy object hierarchy (because of the mandatory lookup fields) to test saving an instance? this is pure SF vanilla (I don't have any code involved with saving the entities, I just want to notify a goddamn external system something happened).